# How to get data from mongodb with duplicated parameters?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jpa, mongotemplate

I have try to create criteria that fetch from data base items.

Here is the code that fetches items from mongo db:

```
public List<Location> findByListOfId(List<String> locationsIds){
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").in(locationsIds));
    return  template.find(query, Location.class);
}
```

here is Location class defenition:

```
@Document("loaction")
@Data
public class Location {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private long order;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;
}
```

And here is the value of input(List locationsIds) in findByListOfId function:

```
List<String> locationsIds = {"5d4eee8047206b6d2df212bb","5d4eee8047206b6d2df212bb","5d4eee8047206b6d2df212bb"}
```

as you can see the input contains the same value three times.

The result that I get from findByListOfId function is a single item with id equal to 5d4eee8047206b6d2df212bb,

while I need to get the numbers of items with the same id as a number of times that exists with in variable(in my case I expect 3 fetched items with id = 5d4eee8047206b6d2df212bb ).

Any idea how this query can be created?

Comment: I had to read your post several times to make clear what you want. So you want for each input id a location object in the method output. Now you only get one because probably an IN query is used and that results in a result of 1 because the id's are equal.

Comment: Why do you want a result of 3 items? I think that's there is a design issue in your service layer and not in your data layer.

Comment: I guess it's not always the same ids in the `locationsIds`.  Am I right thinking you need number of returned documents to match number of _ids in the query regardless of how repetitive they are?

Comment: @JasperHuzen, yes I want it 3 times. What may be an issue with the service?

Answer (score 0):

**Not sure why you want to do it**, but you can do it this way (in Mongo Query Language, you can then translate it in Java).

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/acVNsfw_1hO)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      key: {
        $in: [
          "5d4eee8047206b6d2df212bb",
          "5d4eee8047206b6d2df212bb",
          "5d4eee8047206b6d2df212bb"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "itemsArray": [
        "5d4eee8047206b6d2df212bb",
        "5d4eee8047206b6d2df212bb",
        "5d4eee8047206b6d2df212bb"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$itemsArray"
  },
  
])
```

Using aggregation pipeline, you will add the array as a field using `$addFields` and then `$unwind` it (will give you `x` number of times).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others it's not something you want to do in production code, but I find the question interesting.

@Yahya's answer works with an assumption that the $match stage returns exactly 1 document.

The more generic pipeline to fetch exact number of documents regardless of how unique the key is and how many duplicates are in the query https://mongoplayground.net/p/546QnaFn4lV :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      list: [
        "5d4eee8047206b6d2df212bb",
        "5d4eee8047206b6d2df212bb",
        "6d4eee8047206b6d2df212bc",
        "7d4eee8047206b6d2df212bd"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$list"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "list",
      "foreignField": "key",
      "as": "match"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      match: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$match",
              []
            ]
          },
          [
            {
              _id: null,
              "key": "$list"
            }
          ],
          "$match"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": {
      $first: "$match"
    }
  }
])
```

The first $project passes the list of requested ids to mongo.

The last $project stage returns "null" for requested ids that don't have a matching document.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an aggregate query with required result:

Consider a *collection* with these documents:

```
{ _id: 1, a: 11 }
{ _id: 2, a: 22 }
{ _id: 3, a: 99 }
```

The *query* in `mongo` shell with input documents:

```
var INPUT_IDS = [ 1, 2, 1, 1 ]

db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
      $match: { 
          _id: { $in: INPUT_IDS } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: null, 
          docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $project: {
            docs: { 
                $map: {
                    input: INPUT_IDS,
                    as: "inid",
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: { 
                                matched: { 
                                   $filter: { 
                                      input: "$docs", as: "doc", cond: { $eq: [ "$$inid", "$$doc._id" ] } 
                                   }
                                }
                            },
                            in: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$matched", 0 ] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  },
  { 
      $unwind: "$docs" 
  },
  { 
      $replaceWith: "$docs" 
  }
])
```

*The output:*

```
{ "_id" : 1, "a" : 11 }
{ "_id" : 2, "a" : 22 }
{ "_id" : 1, "a" : 11 }
{ "_id" : 1, "a" : 11 }
```